# Diffuse light model in Open GLES 2.0 android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Why there is stepped,not gradual Diffuse lighting in Openg gles 2.0?

```
 String fragmentShaderCode =

        "precision highp float;" +

                "uniform vec4 u_color;" +
                "varying vec3 v_pos;" +
                "varying vec3 v_normal;" +

                "void main() {" +
                "vec3 u_camera=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);"+
                "vec3 u_lightPosition=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);"+
                "vec3 n_normal=normalize(v_normal);"+
                "vec3 lightvector = normalize(u_lightPosition - v_pos);"+


                "float ambient=0.1;"+
                "float k_diffuse=0.5;"+
                "float cos=(n_normal.x*lightvector.x+n_normal.y*lightvector.y+n_normal.z*lightvector.z)/(length(n_normal)*length(lightvector));"+
                "if(cos<0.0)cos=0.0;"+
                "float an=acos(cos)*(180.0/3.14);"+
                "float diffuse =k_diffuse* (1.0-an/90.0);"+
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK7Yt.png)
                    "gl_FragColor =u_color* (diffuse+ambient);"+

```
                "}";
```

I made to triangles so to form plane with normal (0.0,0.0,1.0). The problem is that light logic works in general correct but with steppy visual effect. So here are my triangles:
  static float triangleCoords[] = {
            // in counterclockwise order:
            5.0f,  5.0f, 0.0f,   // top
           -5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f,
            -5.0f,  -5.0f, 0.0f,

```
        5.0f,  5.0f, 0.0f,
        -5.0f,  -5.0f, 0.0f,
        5.0f,  -5.0f, 0.0f,
       // bottom right
};
static float norms[] = {
        // in counterclockwise order:
        0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   // top
        0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

        0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,  // top
        0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Here is my vertex shader :`private final String vertexShaderCode =

```
        "uniform mat4 prMat;" +
                "uniform mat4 camMat;" +

                "attribute vec3 a_pos;" +
                "varying vec3 v_pos;" +
                "attribute vec3 a_normal;" +
                "varying vec3 v_normal;" +



                "void main() {" +
                "vec4 ver=camMat*vec4(a_pos,1.0);"+

                "v_pos=ver.xyz;"+
                "vec4 v_n=vec4(a_normal,1.0);"+
                "v_normal=normalize(v_n.xyz);"+
                "  gl_Position = prMat*camMat*vec4(a_pos,1.0);" +
                "}";`
```

And some code from render:
        Matrix.translateM(camMat,0,0.0f,0.0f,-7.0f);
        mTriangle.draw(mProjectionMatrix,camMat,0);`

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Try using a dot product of your two unit length vectors, rather than a cosine. The two are equivalent from a functional point of view, but I suspect the implementation is quite different. A picture of your error might help too.

Comment: it Didn t help. i loaded image: there are circles like on the water from thrown stone.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK7Yt.png

Comment: Couple more questions. (1) what device/GPU are you running on? and (2) what EGL color format is the screen?

Comment: 1) Galaxy j2 Prime . Where to see GPU? 2) should i get to know about EGL color format programmatically? what function to use?